# when I refreshed the page in stripe it take payment (incomplete) php

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

Hi I am working in stripe and accept a payment through googlepay all my code working fine and I am accept payment.

This is my code

```
index.php


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Google Pay</title>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <?php include_once 'google.php';?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <a href="/">home</a>
      <h1>Google Pay</h1>

      <div id="payment-request-button">
        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here if the browser supports this type of payment method. -->
      </div>

      <div id="messages" role="alert" style="display: none;"></div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

this is my google.php

```
<?php require("stripe-php-master/init.php"); 
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_456'); $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([ 'amount' => 2099, 'currency' => 'usd', ]);
?>
<script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
        // 1. Initialize Stripe
        const stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51KdBQoC6Dz9QDrkL2stCBgcvY8936IiXUIpIjVD8n4Ug6jTs3QSEUnC9iSHrdPnSI20vxwNC6GTdEmXlBDw8UpP6005xVobO9", {
      apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
    });

        // 2. Create a payment request object
        var paymentRequest = stripe.paymentRequest({
          country: 'US',
          currency: 'usd',
          total: {
            label: 'Demo total',
            amount: 1999,
          },
          requestPayerName: true,
          requestPayerEmail: true,
        });

        // 3. Create a PaymentRequestButton element
        const elements = stripe.elements();
        const prButton = elements.create('paymentRequestButton', {
          paymentRequest: paymentRequest,
        });

        // Check the availability of the Payment Request API,
        // then mount the PaymentRequestButton
        paymentRequest.canMakePayment().then(function (result) {
          if (result) {
            prButton.mount('#payment-request-button');
          } else {
            document.getElementById('payment-request-button').style.display = 'none';
            addMessage('Google Pay support not found. Check the pre-requisites above and ensure you are testing in a supported browser.');
          }
        });

        paymentRequest.on('paymentmethod', async (e) => {
          // Make a call to the server to create a new
          // payment intent and store its client_secret.
          addMessage(`Client secret returned.`);
          let clientSecret = '<?= $paymentIntent->client_secret; ?>';

          // Confirm the PaymentIntent without handling potential next actions (yet).
          let {error, paymentIntent} = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
            clientSecret,
            {
              payment_method: e.paymentMethod.id,
            },
            {
              handleActions: false,
            }
          );

          if (error) {
            addMessage(error.message);

            // Report to the browser that the payment failed, prompting it to
            // re-show the payment interface, or show an error message and close
            // the payment interface.
            e.complete('fail');
            return;
          }
          // Report to the browser that the confirmation was successful, prompting
          // it to close the browser payment method collection interface.
          e.complete('success');

          // Check if the PaymentIntent requires any actions and if so let Stripe.js
          // handle the flow. If using an API version older than "2019-02-11" instead
          // instead check for: `paymentIntent.status === "requires_source_action"`.
          if (paymentIntent.status === 'requires_action') {
            // Let Stripe.js handle the rest of the payment flow.
            let {error, paymentIntent} = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
              clientSecret
            );
            if (error) {
              // The payment failed -- ask your customer for a new payment method.
              addMessage(error.message);
              return;
            }
            addMessage(`Payment ${paymentIntent.status}: ${paymentIntent.id}`);
          }

          addMessage(`Payment ${paymentIntent.status}: ${paymentIntent.id}`);
        });

      });
      const addMessage = (message) => {
      const messagesDiv = document.querySelector('#messages');
      messagesDiv.style.display = 'block';
      messagesDiv.innerHTML += '>' + message + '<br>';
      console.log('StripeSampleDebug:', message);
  }
    </script>`
```

I am stuck whenever i refreshed page it charge payment incomplete and its irritating .I need that when user click on the pay button then they charge payment and it work fine but when i refreshed it charged payment and show in payment section stripe incomplete.

Comment: If you load your page once and make a test payment, does the latest PaymentIntent in your dashboard show up as "Incomplete" or "Succeeded"?

Comment: It is common and often harmless for there to be "Incomplete" payments on your Stripe dashboard. A payment will be "Incomplete" in your dashboard until you charge with it or delete it.

Comment: If your page gets all the say to your `success` message, it sounds like your page is working and those payment intents will probably show up as `Succeeded` on your dashboard. If your page is not getting to your `success` message, can you post the full error message that you are getting and tell us which line of code it is coming from?

Comment: yes payment succeded and I get payment id all working fine but when I refreshed page its  auto charged payment and show incomplete.